# Bash Automatically replacing [0:100] with 1

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm writing a simple graphing script that uses gnuplot, and I use a helper function to construct a .gscript file.

```
add_gscript() {
echo "->>"
echo $1
echo $1 >> plot.gscript
cat plot.gscript
}
```

However after passing the following argument into the function

```
echo "--"
echo 'set xrange [0:$RANGE]'
echo "--"
add_gscript "set xrange [0:100]"
```

where $RANGE has been defined beforehand, I get the following output

```
--
set xrange [0:$RANGE]
--
->>
set xrange 1
set datafile separator ","
set term qt size 800,640
set size ratio .618
set xrange 1
```

Is bash evaluating [0:100] to 1 somehow?

Comment: Always _double-quote_ variable references to have their values treated as _literals_; without quoting, the values are (in most contexts) subject to shell expansions, including word splitting and pathname expansion. `[0:100]` happens to be a valid globbing pattern that matches any file in the current dir. named either  `0` or `:` or `1`.

Comment: so `echo "$1"; echo "$1" >> plot.gscript` and any other unquoted vars. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

A fix was accurately described in comments on the question:

> Always *double-quote* variable references to have their values treated as *literals*; without quoting, the values are (in most contexts) subject to shell expansions, including word splitting and pathname expansion. `[0:100]` happens to be a valid globbing pattern that matches any file in the current dir. named either `0` or `:` or `1`. – [mklement0](http://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)
>
> so `echo "$1"; echo "$1" >> plot.gscript` and any other unquoted vars. Good luck. – [shellter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter)

Double quoting the variables did indeed fix my issue. Thanks!